# Open URL on Windows and a 64-bit Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, url, shellexecute

The following code opens a URL on Windows machines (Excel 2016, 2013, 2010).

I'm trying to make it usable on a 64-bit Mac (Excel for Mac v. 16.22, Office 365 install) as well.

I have tried a number of iterations for finding the Mac library "libc.dylib", and usually get the "Runtime Error '53'.  File not found 'libc.dylib'" error.  Once I got the error "Runtime Error '453'.  File not found '/usr/lib/libc.dylib'".

Here's the code that produced the 453 error:

```
Option Explicit

Enum W32_Window_State
    Show_Normal = 1
    Show_Minimized = 2
    Show_Maximized = 3
    Show_Min_No_Active = 7
    Show_Default = 10
End Enum

#If Mac Then
    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function system Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Private Declare Function system Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String) As Long
    #End If
#Else
    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
            Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
            ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
            ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
            Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
            ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
            ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
            ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
    #End If
#End If

Public Function OpenURL(URL As String, WindowState As W32_Window_State) As Boolean

    'Opens passed URL with default application, or Error Code (<32) upon error

    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim lngHWnd As LongPtr
        Dim lngReturn As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim lngHWnd As Long
        Dim lngReturn As Long
    #End If

    #If Mac Then
        lngReturn = system("open -a Safari --args " & URL)
    #Else
        lngReturn = ShellExecute(lngHWnd, "open", URL, vbNullString, _
            vbNullString, WindowState)
    #End If

    OpenURL = (lngReturn > 32)  ' With Mac, this may return a dummy variable, but we're going to do it anyways.

End Function
```

In addition to the code here, I have tried using colons in the file path in place of the slashes. That gave me an error of '53, file not found' as well.

Comment: In addition to the code here, I have tried using colons in the file path in place of the slashes.  That gave me an error of '53, file not found' as well.